# How do I check whether gcc supports -march=native?

Tags: gcc

I notice that gcc on OSX Snow Leopard doesn't support -march=native. What command can I put in the configure script to detect whether the option is available?

Comment: Try to compile hello world with -march=native and analyze gcc's exit code? Something like: echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > test.c && gcc -march=native -o test test.c and then grab $? to a var and use it.

Comment: @maverik. Hmmm, no clean way?

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work:

```
echo "" | gcc -fsyntax-only -march=native -xc -
```